# Android - Does CountDownTimer.cancel() not work on all phones?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am currently creating a game where the countdowntimer must be frequently incremented. I successfully created a countdown timer that uses cancel outside of onTick and cancels the timer. I also have my CountDownTimer (Timer) set as a private static which also allows me to call it outside of my startTimer class.

My class startTimer(int x) calls the timer.

My class resetTimer creates all the necessary changes and then calls timer.cancel() and startTimer(x) to reset the timer.

This successful works on my gs6. While Alpha testing on my girlfriends phone. Timer.cancel does not seem to be recognized?

While debugging. I simply wanted to check what happens when the timer.cancel is used. On my galaxyS6 the timer stops decrementing. On my girlsfriends galaxyS4 it ends up running the first timer and another one on top of it. Timer is set to be the only timer to be manipulated. So does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

I have a solution in mind. When onFinish occurs check to see if timer==null if not skip the end game calls. Im sure since im only changing timer it shouldnt be null. But why is it not canceling on my gf phone? Thank you :)

Comment: Are they both running the same android version?

Comment: Hey John. Their versions are different hers is Kit Kat and I have lollipop. But CountDownTimer.cancel should work for both right?

Comment: also if any confusion timer.cancel() is being called inside of resetTimer. And I think reset timer is being called inside onTick... hmm could it be possible that it's simply considering timer.cancel() as being called inside of  onTick? even though it actually is not?

Comment: Idk why, but the `cancel` method doesn't work inside the `CountDownTimer`. I had to use it outside.